# How do I stop my laptop battery draining (Ubuntu 20.04)?

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

Yesterday my Asus laptop's battery started going down fast. There is no over heating or anything like that; it simply starts going down when not plugged in. Since turning it on just a minute ago it has gone from 97% to 76%.

I have tried letting it drain and then pushing to power button for 30 seconds but that didn't sort it. I have also used TimeShift to go back to before this started and that hasn't solved it. I have installed 'laptop-mode-tools' (as it didn't have anything like that installed) and that didn't solve it. I am fed up and cannot take the laptop to any repair place because of the pandemic.

What do I do?

Comment: Have tried two things which seem to work (though I'll have to keep an eye on it). I reinstalled 'laptop-mode-tools' and permanently disabled Bluetooth. Hopefully this will solve the problem. Not sure if I should mark this as the right answer but I will if it works.